# how to debug/fix index out bounds error in pixels array?

Tags: c, bitmap, blur

im having issue with my code. It is giving this error message below because of the last block of code ( in the "middle of the image" coding). i have tried debugging but it didn't help. can you please have a look. i'm following the steps and not going outside of array but not sure why it is giving error

> runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]

my code is below

```
R=round(ceil(image[i][k].rgbtRed+image[i][k-1].rgbtRed+image[i-1][k].rgbtRed+image[i-1][k-1].rgbtRed+image[i+1][k].rgbtRed+image[i+1][k-1].rgbtRed+image[i][k+1].rgbtRed+image[i-1][k+1].rgbtRed+image[i+1][k+1].rgbtRed)/9);
G=round(ceil(image[i][k].rgbtGreen+image[i][k-1].rgbtGreen+image[i-1][k].rgbtGreen+image[i-1][k-1].rgbtGreen+image[i+1][k].rgbtGreen+image[i+1][k-1].rgbtGreen+image[i][k+1].rgbtGreen+image[i-1][k+1].rgbtGreen+image[i+1][k+1].rgbtGreen)/9);
B=round(ceil(image[i][k].rgbtBlue+image[i][k-1].rgbtBlue+image[i-1][k].rgbtBlue+image[i-1][k-1].rgbtBlue+image[i+1][k].rgbtBlue+image[i+1][k-1].rgbtBlue+image[i][k+1].rgbtBlue+image[i-1][k+1].rgbtBlue+image[i+1][k+1].rgbtBlue)/9);
```

Comment: did you try to set a break point on these pixels arrays and se why your expression exceeds the array bounds? it should be easy. we cant help because we need to see all the code and its runtime issue. so you need to debug!

Comment: Hard to tell given the lack of context, but your issue likely arises because `i` and/or `k` is 0 at some point.

Comment: You will likely have a similar issue on the other boundary of your image, where `i+1` and `k+1` access outside the valid image area.  Typical approaches to solving edge-conditions for blurring are: (1) just ignore edges; (2) only blur the available pixels on an edge; (3) treat the edge as a "mirror"; (4) clamp to the edge.

Comment: Your code doesn't show which values `i` and `k` have.
Basically if you define `image[N][M]` (where `N` and `M` are the sizes of each dimension) which you address with `image[x][y]` you will have to make sure `x` is always in the range `0 .. N-1` and `y` in `0 .. M-1`.
So when you have for example `image[i][k-1]` then `i` must never be outside range `0 .. N-1` and `k` must never be outside `1 .. M`.